# Ruby: combining normal and bitwise comparisons

Tags: ruby, comparison, bit-manipulation

This seems like a foolishly simple problem.  I'm searching through a list of users, using a bitwise operator to determine whether first and last names match the provided term (I didn't write this code, it's legacy).

Now I need to add in a third condition - that their state is not 'disabled.'  Without this third condition, the search works as expected.  However, when I add the other and statement, it breaks.

```
@users = User.reject{|user| user.first_name !~ /^#{term}/i && user.last_name !~ /^#{term}/i } #Works as expected - returns users matching 'term'

@users = User.reject{|user| user.first_name !~ /^#{term}/i && user.last_name !~ /^#{term}/i && user.suspended? } # Does not work - returns a full list of active users, as well as any suspended users that match.

@users = User.reject{|user| user.first_name !~ /^#{term}/i && user.last_name !~ /^#{term}/i }
@users.reject!{|user| user.suspended?} # This combination works, but I feel like there should be a way to condense it into a single line
```

I've also tried adding some parentheses around the first two conditions, but that doesn't help either.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Read up on DeMorgan's law, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not bitwise operation here, `!~` is a negated regex match (think "doesn't match").

For your actual question:

```
@users = User.reject{|user| user.first_name !~ /^#{term}/i && user.last_name !~ /^#{term}/i || user.suspended? }
```

Basically this says: 'reject the user if this first_name and last_name don't match the provided regular expression or if the user is suspended'. Your version only worked for users with invalid names who ALSO where suspended (because of the `&&`).

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you move some of these conditions into named scopes. Also, this will move your searching into MySQL. I wonder how that will effect performance?

```
scope :first_name_not_like, lambda {|term| where(["first_name NOT RLIKE '^#{?}'", term])}
scope :last_name_not_like, lambda {|term| where(["last_name NOT RLIKE '^#{?}'", term])}
scope :not_suspended, lambda { where(["suspended NOT true"])}
```

Or something like that?

Then you can do

```
@users = User.first_name_not_like(term).last_name_not_like_(term).not_suspended
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your final `&&` should be an `||`

```
@users = User.reject{|user| user.first_name !~ /^#{term}/i && user.last_name !~ /^#{term}/i || user.suspended? }
```